# setBounds image width 100%

Tags: android, image, width, setbounds

Can I setBounds the full width photos the textView

sorry i cant good speak English

my code :

```
   public class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imgN);
        if (source.equals("img1")) {
            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1);
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 150);
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

width = 100%
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

Comment: What is not working with your code?

Comment: my code is working , i want width = 100% or match parrent